# Apache Spark--Need to implement withColumn dynamically based on resultant metadata map

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am having a use case where i need to do some data corrections on already loaded data.Given that metadata is in hbase with the logical primarykeys under one colfamily and columnUpdates under another column family. Assume that i am having a filtered dataframe with a single record for which i need to do the updation(filtered by using spark sql).The colNames& Colvalues are in a java Map.I knew that we can apply withColunmm inorder to update or to add a new col to the existing DF,but in this case i need to apply the withColumn multiple times based on my metadata i.e. the no of cols for which the data needs to be corrected.i cant do this one in a for loop by iterating the map as Dataframes are immutable and also i m not encouraged to use the switch case.Also having a limitation that should not use scala API.

```
Dataset<Row> existingdata = sparksession.read
      .format(com.databricks.spark.avro)
      .load(myhdfslocation);

Map<byte[],byte[]> colUpdates = result.getFamily("TK")//result of hbase get
Set<byte[]> colUpdateKeys = colUpdates.keySet();
for(byte[] eachkey : colUpdateKeys ){
    Dataset<Row> updatedDF =  
             existingdata.withColumn(
                existingdata.col(Bytes.toString(eachkey)),
                "value from themetadatamap"
             );
}
```

So Far i am having 2 approaches one is use the switch case(which is not optimal as it is not a good way to keep so many switch cases) and the other is reading the hbase metadata as a spark dataframe and then apply the spark joins to get the resultant dataset.
If anyone can suggest the best way to implement this usecase it will be really Helpful.:)

Comment: Is `"value from themetadatamap"` coming from the same `existingdata` data frame?

Comment: Nope.it is the value from colupdates map.this map is having the column name that is to be updated as key and the value is the column value.

Comment: Existingdata =existingdata.withColumn(.....) This line will throw reintialization error as the dataframes are immutable, if a dataframe is initialized once it can't be changed for a new value.

Comment: Data frames are immutable, that means you cannot change a data frame object. That does not mean that you cannot replace the object value of a data frame variable with a different object. `existingdata = existingdata.withColumn()` will create a new data frame based on the old one, then overwrite the value of the variable.

Comment: Even I thought in the similar manner and kept similar kind of code but during run time it is throwing reinitialization error.. you can give a try on spark shell by executing similar kind of code..it is not allowing even to change the reference variable..anyway I will run again and will let you know.

Comment: how about something like this, this is scala code though...     val updatedDF = colUpdateKeys.foldLeft(existingdata)((df, name) => df.withColumn(name,“value from themetadatamap”))

Comment: Tq @Ernest Kiwele. Able to change the reference variable of a dataframe through code.with the same piece of code I was not able to do so earlier (before posting it here)bcz of some dependency jar conflicts. The other change was inside withColumn , I added the 2nd argument as a literal Obj. Now it is working as expected. Tq all. :)

Comment: @DijendraPushadapu Good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you cannot mutate a data frame, you can update the variable referring to it :-)

```
for(byte[] eachkey : colUpdateKeys ){
    existingdata =  
             existingdata.withColumn(
                existingdata.col(Bytes.toString(eachkey)),
                "value from themetadatamap"
             );
}
```

This will overwrite the `existingdata` variable with the value of the latest data frame in the lineage, such that after the loop, `existingdata` has all columns.